# Visual Studio and Mobile Phone Development

Tags: android, asp.net, mobile, visual-studio-2012

If I wanted to target mobile phones (Android, Windows Phone 8, etc.) using HTML5, CSS, and Javascript client, which Visual Studio 2012 project type would I use?

I presume ASP.Net, but I do not see any further breakdown that mentions phone or javascript.  Okay, I am not sure what language ASP.Net uses anyways.

Is the output language configurable in ASP.Net?

How is javascript implemented?

If not ASP.Net, which exact project type targets HTML5, CSS, and Javascript client so that I can target mobile phone development?

Comment: ASP.NET can use a variety of different languages and is a server side language (ie: it really has nothing to do directly with HTML/CSS/Javascript). C# and VB are the two most common languages used. I would suggest watching some online courses on how to create websites and to learn HTML4, Javascript, and C# ASP.NET before trying to go into something where most professionals are still learning and adjusting (HTML5 and Responsive Web Design)

Comment: As CoderSeven said, there are multiple options. That said, I'd look at ASP.NET MVC 4 for mobile. It has jQuery Mobile baked in (you can obviously remove it if you so choose) and with the whole Razor engine setup, you realistically could focus primarily on HTML5/CSS/JavaScript and abstract, somewhat, from the .NET development. If you're avoiding the .NET stuff entirely, well, Visual Studio may be overkill (unless you want the intellisense features).

Comment: I already use C#.Net for the desktop and have used ASP.Net for a website a couple of times.  I wanted to target mobile devices and wanted to leverage Visual Studio, as I know the interface.  The reason for HTML5 as a front end is that I am considering using a control suite (DXTREME), which uses what I mentioned and works with Visual Studio.  What I am new to is modern mobile application development.

Answer (score 3):

If you're learning ASP.NET then your best bet is to start with MVC because you can avail of the new [Mobile Project Template](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes).

This tutorial will teach you the basics of how to work with mobile features in an ASP.NET MVC 4 Web application:

[ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Features](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)

jQuery and jQuery UI libraries are also included in ASP.NET MVC 4:

[New MVC4 Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic2.aspx)

I also suggest you take a look at CSS Media Queries in conjunction with Responsive Web Design (RWD):

[Responsive Web Design](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/400502/Responsive-Web-Design)

Last but not  least, take a look at HTML5 Boilerplate project:

[Getting Started Using HTML5 Boilerplate](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/06/05/getting-started-using-html5-boilerplate.aspx)

Previous question with some good resource links:

[How to convert an existing ASP.NET website to HTML 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256171/how-to-convert-an-existing-asp-net-website-to-html-5/5557192#5557192)